# Message: not in namespace - Gobal Variale not usable in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, static, namespaces, global-variables

I have the problem, that the follow code will not do that what i want :-(

**in .cs:**

```
....

    namespace Garten
    {
        public static class MyVar
        {
            public static string Hintergrund;
        }

....
```

**in xaml:**

```
....
xmlns:Garten="clr-namespace:Garten"
....
<TextBox Background = "{x:Static Garten:MyVar.Hintergrund}"/>
....
```

I got this message:
The name "MyVar" is not in namespace 'clr-namespace:Garten

What can i do?

Comment: Rebuild your project. Be aware however that `string` is not a valid type for the `Background` property.

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks, thats it.